# How to get data out of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array as such from a txt file:

```
[[1, 4, 6, 2, 5]
[3, 4, 3, 5, 4]
[5, 3, 6, 7, 1]]
[[3, 4, 2, 5, 8]
[5, 2, 7, 5, 4]
[4, 2, 4, 4, 0]]
[[2, 5, 3, 1, 4]
[3, 8, 5, 6, 2]
[2, 6, 7, 4, 2]]
```

I want to take the mean of the 3rd row for each group of results. so each group is in a double bracket `[[1, 4, 6, 2, 5]
 [3, 4, 3, 5, 4]
 [5, 3, 6, 7, 1]]` is one group,

`[[3, 4, 2, 5, 8]
 [5, 2, 7, 5, 4]
 [4, 2, 4, 4, 0]]` is the second group etc.)

How do I access each group individually?

Comment: something like `a[0]`?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please provide a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've already tried so that we can better understand how to help you

Comment: You first need to parse your text file in order to convert it to Python objects, probably lists of "matrixes". Then you'll be able to do some calculation. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the mean of the third row of each group with:

```
>>> data[:,2].mean(axis=1)
array([4.4, 2.8, 4.2])
```

If `data` is for example:

```
>>> data
array([[[1, 4, 6, 2, 5],
        [3, 4, 3, 5, 4],
        [5, 3, 6, 7, 1]],

       [[3, 4, 2, 5, 8],
        [5, 2, 7, 5, 4],
        [4, 2, 4, 4, 0]],

       [[2, 5, 3, 1, 4],
        [3, 8, 5, 6, 2],
        [2, 6, 7, 4, 2]]])
```

then by slicing, we obtain the third row of each group:

```
>>> data[:,2]
array([[5, 3, 6, 7, 1],
       [4, 2, 4, 4, 0],
       [2, 6, 7, 4, 2]])
```

Then for each row we can calculate the mean with `.mean(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

If your data is like this, This code will work fine

```
lst =[ 
[[1, 4, 6, 2, 5],[3, 4, 3, 5, 4],[5, 3, 6, 7, 1]],
[[3, 4, 2, 5, 8],[5, 2, 7, 5, 4],[4, 2, 4, 4, 0]],
[[2, 5, 3, 1, 4],[3, 8, 5, 6, 2],[2, 6, 7, 4, 2]]
     ]

import numpy as np

means = []

for i in lst:
    means.append(np.mean(i[2]))

print(means)

>> [4.4, 2.8, 4.2]
```